# Erro na captura do teste cucumber/capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, testes-automatizados

Preciso realizar meus testes, mas a está ocorrendo alguns erros no código, mas o cucumber não está apresentando o erro, somente traz o erro :`

```
incompatible encoding regexp match (Windows-1252 regexp with UTF-8 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber -p html_report -p chrome features/specs/solic_new_estabelecimento.feature:13

Mas o erro não se encontra na linha 13 e já está especificado o `# encoding: UTF-8` na .feature. Não sei mais oque fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marco, comecei a ter esse erro recentemente e mesmo pesquisando muito não obtive uma resposta.

Aqui cheguei a solução e acredito que irá ser sua solução também: Caso tenha alguma pasta com nome composto e com espaço, mude para um nome simples ou adicione hifen, exemplo: pasta-com-nome-composto

Após fazer isso aqui no meu projeto consegui corrigir o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Esse mesmo erro estava acontecendo comigo e era o nome da pasta do meu projeto que estava dando o problema. Tipo tinha um ~ e um ç no nome, e ao remover, o Capybara voltou a exibir os erros corretamente na linha de comando.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser problema no seu Windowns tenta isso aqui:

erros windows utf 8 acessar painel de controle > regiao > aba administrativo alterar localidade do sistema > marcar checkbox Beta: usar unicode UTF-8 para suporte de linguagem mundial